# How can I determine whether a device supports 4G?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Depending on the network connectivity I would like to show varying content, so I would like to determine whether a device supports 4G or 3G connectivity. How can I do this? I tried looking for a solution, but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cordova-plugin-network-information` plugin to check the current network state of the user

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        var networkState = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        console.log('network state: ',networkState);
        if (networkState == Connection.CELL_4G) {
           //show the contents to the user while user is in 4g
        }else{
           //show the contents to the user if not 4g
        }
    })
```

The available values of the network state are

- Connection.WIFI
- Connection.CELL_2G
- Connection.CELL_3G
- Connection.CELL_4G
- Connection.NONE
- Connection.CELL
- Connection.UNKNOWN
- Connection.ETHERNET

Comment: @Kadir Damene, Please accept the answer if it helps.